# porque no salen las peticiones de httpClient. Ionic 4 angular 7

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7, ionic4

Estoy haciendo una sencilla aplicación en ionic 4 y angular 7. El problema que tengo es que HttpClient no funciona, automáticamente me regresa error cuando la aplicación esta siendo ejecutada en un celular con android. Lo raro es que funciona perfectamente en modo de desarrollo.

Investigando más sobre el error que produce es este. La petición no se esta creando correctamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo en como comentaba en el escritorio sale perfectamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el servicio que hice para hacer el login

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { JwtResponseInterface } from "../models/jwt-response";
import { UserInterface } from "../models/user";
import { from, Observable, BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  AUTH_SERVER = "http://my-proyect-barcodes.esy.es";
  authSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  private token: string;
  private headers;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders()
      // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
      .set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
      .set("Content-Type", "application/json");
  }

  login(user: UserInterface): Observable<JwtResponseInterface> {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<JwtResponseInterface>(`${this.AUTH_SERVER}/api/login`, user, {
        headers: this.headers
      })
      .pipe(
        tap((res: JwtResponseInterface) => {
          if (res) {
            this.saveToken(res.access_token, res.expires_at, res.token_type);
          }
        })
      );
  }



  private saveToken(
    token: string,
    expires_at: string,
    token_type: string
  ): void {
    localStorage.setItem("ACCESS_TOKEN", token);
    localStorage.setItem("EXPIRES_IN", expires_at);
    localStorage.setItem("EXPIRES_TYPE", token_type);
    this.token = token;
  }

  private getToken(): string {
    if (!this.token) {
      this.token = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    }

    return this.token;
  }

  checkAuth() {
    let date = new Date(localStorage.getItem("EXPIRES_IN"));
    let token = localStorage.getItem("ACCESS_TOKEN");
    let now = new Date();
    if (date < now) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Efectivamente es un error de conexión. alguien sabe ¿Por qué se produce?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo veo en la primera imagen una petición que aún no se ha completado (no hay status) y en la segunda una petición errónea (status 422). En el primer caso parece que no es capaz de conectar con el servidor ¿Problemas de conectividad o de DNS?

Comment: ya agregue el error más espesifico

Comment: ¿Alguien encontró la solución a este problema? Me está ocurriendo exactamente lo mismo...